# .NET three columns

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have `IEnumerable<Class1> result` (for example) in my View (ASP .NET MVC 3), and now i show it like two columns:

```
<div id="left_column">
@foreach (PeopleTale pt in ((IEnumerable<PeopleTale>)ViewBag.PeopleTales).Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 1))
{
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">@pt.NameAn</a>
    </div>
}
</div>

<div id="center_column">
@foreach (PeopleTale pt in ((IEnumerable<PeopleTale>)ViewBag.PeopleTales).Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0))
{
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">@pt.NameAn</a>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

So, nice, but i have three columns on my HTML page. Is it possible with LINQ where to display my data for three columns? Dont know how to do it with simple and beautiful solution =\

```
<div id="left_column">    
</div>

<div id="center_column">
</div>

<div id="right_column">
</div>
```

My data is not fixed, so i dont know how much i could Skip and Take.
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also consider using partial view (I'm using `IEnumerable<PeopleTale>` as model here, for better readability):

```
<div id="left_column">
@Html.Partial("PeopleTalesList", Model.Where((pt, i) => i % 3 == 2))
</div>
<div id="center_column">
@Html.Partial("PeopleTalesList", Model.Where((pt, i) => i % 3 == 1))
</div>
<div id="right_column">
@Html.Partial("PeopleTalesList", Model.Where((pt, i) => i % 3 == 0))
</div>
```

Your `PeopleTalesList.cshtml` partial view file will look like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<PeopleTale>
@foreach (var pt in Model)
{
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">@pt.NameAn</a>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do exactly what you are doing

```
<div id="left_column">
@foreach (PeopleTale pt in ((IEnumerable<PeopleTale>)ViewBag.PeopleTales).Where((x, i)  => i % 3== 2))
{
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">@pt.NameAn</a>
</div>
}
</div>

<div id="center_column">
@foreach (PeopleTale pt in ((IEnumerable<PeopleTale>)ViewBag.PeopleTales).Where((x, i) => i % 3== 1))
{
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">@pt.NameAn</a>
</div>
}
</div>


<div id="right_column">
@foreach (PeopleTale pt in ((IEnumerable<PeopleTale>)ViewBag.PeopleTales).Where((x, i) => i % 3== 0))
{
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">@pt.NameAn</a>
</div>
}
</div>
```

i couldn't get something better

Comment: It would probably make sense to cache the PeopleTale collection if it is an expensive query, since you will be iterating it three times.